# Get UTF-8 Filename from Content-Disposition Header

Tags: go, mime

When I try to get the filename from the Content-Disposition Header the go function `mime.ParseMediaType()` fails with the error `mime: invalid media parameter`

---

I already found out, that it works with the normal filename format:

`attachment; filename="Geotag_Stamp%20(1)%20(1).jpg"` <- works

But with the UTF-8 filename (defined in [rfc6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#page-5)) it failes with the error given in the first paragraph:

`attachment; filename*=UTF-8''"Geotag_Stamp%20(1)%20(1).jpg"` <- Fails

---

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "mime"
)

func main() {
    d, params, err := mime.ParseMediaType(`attachment; filename="Geotag_Stamp%20(1)%20(1).jpg"`)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("**Normal Filename error:", err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println("Normal:", d, params)
    d, params, err = mime.ParseMediaType(`attachment; filename*=UTF-8''"Geotag_Stamp%20(1)%20(1).jpg"`)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("**UTF-8 Filename error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("UTF-8",d, params)
}
```

[On the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iSXX8DG6g3n)

---

Is it possible that the stdlib does not support the UTF-8 version of Content-Disposition->Filename ?

Comment: RFC 6266 is "just" a proposed standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quotes must surround the header value:

```
attachment; filename*="UTF-8''Geotag_Stamp%20(1)%20(1).jpg"
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aG9zp-9wVkG)